# Create external table with select statement in hive SQL(.hql)

Tags: google-bigquery, hive, bigdata

I am working to convert one of the hive sql scripts to bigquery , need some help in understanding the behaviour of below hql statement

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ext_table
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION '{outputBucket}/ext_table_file'
AS SELECT
*
FROM mytable

If the the output bucket already contains a file "ext_table_file", will this query load the data from the file and the select statement or it will overwrite(truncate and load) the external file with data from select statement?

Expecting to understand the behaviour of above script for conversion to bq since i dont have access to hive sql terminal. in bq we need to maintain all the data in the table and not the external data source.